# How does mutual flux in a synchronous generator remain constant like in a transformer?

Tags: electric-machine, magnetic-flux, flux

Given is the flux per pole of of a synchronous generator
[image]

[image]

1)Is it field/rotor flux per pole ?

2)The generated emf per phase is given by

E=4.44Nfφ where φ is the flux per pole

But from transformers, we know that the secondary develops it's own flux which opposes the primary flux so the primary flux has to be increased in order to keep the mutual flux constant.

In the same way, once emf is geneated in the stator it creates its own stator flux
φ'. How does rotor flux φ deal with stator flux φ' such that net flux φ" is constant like in a transformer ?

Comment: As long there is no current, the total flux is a stator flux. When it is loaded, the rotor isn't aligned to output voltage vector.

Comment: The rotor flux is constant, but the stator flux is continuously changing, hence the induced sinewave or the basic concept of a generator.